# deploy solidity ethereum to parachain with ExhaustsResources error

Tags: parachain, frontier, evm, ethereum, solidity

I can deploy a few Ethereum smart contracts into my parachain via Hardhat.

But those are only normal contracts. All the upgradeable contracts and ERC777 contract cannot be deployed with the ExhaustsResources error:

```
ProviderError: submit transaction to pool failed: 
Pool(InvalidTransaction(InvalidTransaction::ExhaustsResources))
```

Reference: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-errors.

my hardhat.config.ts

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    parachain: {
      url: `${PARACHAIN_CHAIN_URL}`,
      chainId: 1345,
      //gasPrice:...//causes Payment error
      gas: 25e6,//these also work: 7e6, 2e6
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: `${MNEMONIC}`,
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
        initialIndex: 0,
        count: 20,
        passphrase: "",
      },
    },
    rinkeby: {
      url: `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/${INFURA_API_KEY}`,
      chainId: 4,
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("20", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 25e6,
      accounts: [`0x${OWNERPK}`, `0x${USER1PK}`, `0x${USER2PK}`],
    },
  },
};
```

I can run the same deployment script to deploy contracts to Rinkeby network, but why the same script cannot deploy upgradeable and ERC777 contracts to my parachain???

I suspect my parachain has certain limitations on deployment sizes...

- Where is that set?
- How can I increase such limitation?

Comment: See some solutions here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/how-to-add-frontier-code-as-a-dependency-to-substrate-parachain-template-based-p/4295

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be the problem of the deployer Hardhat!

See this post: [How to add Frontier code as a dependency to substrate-parachain-template based parachain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4227/how-to-add-frontier-code-as-a-dependency-to-substrate-parachain-template-based-p/4295#4295)

All the upgradeable contracts and ERC777 could not be deployed because Hardhat was running too fast and that overwhelmed my parachain, hence "ExhaustsResources" error!

Now I can deploy all my upgradeable contracts and ERC777(deploy ERC1820 first!) via Hardhat or Truffle.

my hardhat.config.ts:

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    parachain: {
      url: `${PARACHAIN_EVM_ENDPOINT}`,
      chainId: 1234,
      //gasPrice: 0,
      //gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "gwei").toNumber(),//causing Payment error
      gas: 25e6,//7e6,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: `${MNEMONIC}`,
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
        initialIndex: 0,
        count: 20,
        passphrase: "",
      },
    },
}
```

AND you must use `await` for all asynchronous operations!

AND you must wait for block confirmation as shown below for Hardhat code:

```
token = await Token.deploy(tokenName, tokenSymbol);
await token.deployTransaction.wait(blockConfirmation);
```

For Truffle, add this `confirmations` in your truffle-config.js:

```
    parachain: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(MNEMONIC, `${PARA_CHAIN_URL}`),//PARA_CHAIN_URL=http://127.0.0.1:7272
      network_id: 2045,
      production: true, 
      confirmations: 2, //to wait for enough confirmation
      skipDryRun: true, //true to skip simulations
    },
```

This `confirmation` slows the deployment down so the parachain can have time to make deployment properly.

Answer (score 1):

`BlockWeights` was set [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/dbdbef95c84644328bee60bd170d79814c04e32b/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L204).

Tips:

If you have sudo pallet on your chain. You could try [`sudo_unchecked_weight`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/dbdbef95c84644328bee60bd170d79814c04e32b/frame/sudo/src/lib.rs#L156-L180). To verify if this is the root cause.

Comment: I can go to Polkadot.js > Developer > Sudo > SudoUncheckedWeight(call, weight) ... then there are so many different options for function names. What should I do?