# submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(TemporarilyBanned)

Tags: parachain, frontier, substrate-parachain-template

When I tried to deploy an Ethereum smart contract to my parachain's Frontier EVM, I got this error:

```
running deployment script...
owner: 0x6Be02d1d3665660d22FF9624b7BE0551ee1Ac91b
user1: 0x735113e044BFce4DebA5da7BfBc96A3e6A96F6Da
owner balance: 340282366920938463463.319096430768211455
user1 balance: 0.0
about to deploy contract...
Error: Returned error: submit transaction to pool failed: Pool(TemporarilyBanned)
    at Object.ErrorResponse (...ethereumProject/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at ...ethereumProject/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (...ethereumProject/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (...ethereumProject/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request-event-target.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (...ethereumProject/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (...ethereumProject/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (...ethereumProject/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  data: null
}
```

I found this old Stackoverflow post in the general forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270007/in-substrate-what-does-code-1012-transaction-is-temporarily-banned-mean

- how can I use -ltxpool=log ? in the command that launches my parachain?

I have found those Substrate code:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e740bc89d097a38d922d5619b55e0c7e8664a6c/client/transaction-pool/src/graph/rotator.rs#L94

```
pub struct PoolRotator<Hash>
...
pub fn clear_timeouts(&self, now: &Instant)
```

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/2b43a43dd0dca9a4bb2e3b3253af0e44f71a56ba/core/transaction-pool/graph/src/pool.rs#L128

```
pub struct Pool<B: ChainApi>
...
self.rotator.clear_timeouts(&now);
```

I think I should call this function: `pub fn clear_timeouts(&self, now: &Instant)`, but don't know how to do that...

- should I call that from my parachain as an extrinsic function?
- should I call that from Polkadot.js ?
- if so, how can I make such a function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `Pool(TemporarilyBanned)`, you need to wait for asynchronous operations and wait for block confirmations... see [deploy solidity ethereum to parachain with ExhaustsResources error](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/deploy-solidity-ethereum-to-parachain-with-exhaustsresources-error/4322#4322)